# How to run the aws command contained in a Bash script without configuring it?

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to run bash script to upload the file into S3 bucket

like : `aws s3 <cp xyx.txt>  s3://<tos3bucket>`

Is that possible to run the `aws` command without configuring using `$ aws configure` like below detail.

Either by external file or by command `-u 'key' -p 'value'` is there?

My aim is run the `aws` cli without configuring it

I have tried by below

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
```

But I got:

> upload failed: ...  Unable to locate credentials

If I configure `aws` it works.

Comment: Looks like you created some variables, but didn't export to make them *environment* variables; you want `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` after assigning them, before you execute your `aws` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run the aws CLI command without configuring or export the key-value but keep in mind add space before the command to avoid command writing to history.

```
<space> REGION=us-west-2 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="You_key" AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="secret" aws ec2 describe-instances
```